# chown -R vs chmod 777 -Rf, tomcat catalina.sh permission denied

Tags: tomcat

I am running tomcat via Kubernetes. In my DockerFile, I am defining this:

```
...
RUN chown -R myuser:myuser /tomcat
USER myuser:myuser
...
```

However, this gives me

```
/bin/sh: /tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: Permission denied
```

I have add this line in order for it to work:

```
RUN chmod 777 -Rf /tomcat
```

I don't understand why I need to do `chmod`. My understanding of `chown` is giving ownership to the user (myuser) (https://linuxize.com/post/linux-chown-command/).

I need to read/write and execute files in /tomcat. I found `777` is not good practice due to security reason. Why do I need `chmod` and what is the best approach to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

What it looks like is that file wasn't executable which was giving the permission denied error. That would happen even if root were to try to execute the file with those permissions.

All you needed was `chmod u+x /tomcat/bin/catalina.sh` and it would have worked.

You don't want the entirety of `/tomcat` to be world writable. As there isn't anyway to know which files should have what permissions, you'll need to either reinstall tomcat or look at an installation on another system and set the permissions to mirror those. To start with, you can run `chmod 755 /tomcat/bin/catalina.sh` and go from there.